# Error Generating OpenAPI doc using the endpoint-framework-tools (unclear documentation)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

(Intro)
I am undergoing some tutorials on google cloud endpoint using the google documentation. I have managed to run my first API but i am having an error generating an OpenAPI document using the endpoint-framework-tools

(Question/Issue)
Long story short, I am having an "unclear" error while trying to generate the OpenAPI document of my google cloud endpoint project.
Official google docs [(here)](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/adding-api-management) states the below method to generate the file:

```
  endpoints-framework-tools-2.0.0-beta.11/bin/endpoints-framework-tools\
 get-openapi-doc \
  --hostname=YOUR-PROJECT-ID.appspot.com \
  --war=target/echo-1.0-SNAPSHOT \
  com.example.echo.Echo
```

They do not specify what is "com.eample.echo.Echo".
Trying to run the command by replacing com.example by my package path I am receiving the below confusing error.

```
Error:  co.mydomain.eliokhattar.myapplication.backend.MyEndpoint
```

replacing the above package by any other package still gives the same error.

Can any one advise or provide a clear tutorial on how to use this endpoints-framework-tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue, and it was related to the fact that i was not mentionning the -classpath parameter when invoking endpoint framework.
The below command worked fine.

```
endpoints-framework-tools-2.0.0-beta.11/bin/endpoints-framework-tools \
 get-openapi-doc \
 --hostname=iccloudendpoint.appspot.com \
 --war=/Users/eliokhattar/endpints-test/IcExteranlTutorialDemo/icSysBackend/src/main/webapp \
 --classpath=/Users/eliokhattar/endpints-test/IcExteranlTutorialDemo/icSysBackend/build/classes/main/ co.mydomain.eliokhattar.myapplication.backend.MyEndpoint
```

On the other hand i am having a different unrelated error now.

Answer (score 0):

You want the compiled application.  You are pointing to your source code.  Try something like "icSysBackend/build/exploded-app".

Also, you want the format of the class to be based on where it is in the package.  Think "com.etc.etc.Class"  not "com/etc/etc/Class".