# Error generating OpenAPI doc using endpoints-framework-tools

Tags: java, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have been trying to add API management to my Google Cloud Endpoints (2.0) API.

I have been following Google's documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/adding-api-management), however when running the **endpoints-framework-tools get-openapi-doc** command, as follows:

```
endpoints-framework-tools-2.0.8/bin/endpoints-framework-tools \
get-openapi-doc \
--hostname=myapp-id.appspot.com \
--war=target/backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT \
uk.co.myproject.backend.MyServiceEndpoint
```

I just the following response: **Error: uk.co.myproject.backend.MyServiceEndpoint**

I have tried adding the folders containing all of my .class files to the **--classpath** argument, as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348825/error-generating-openapi-doc-using-the-endpoint-framework-tools-unclear-documen), but it seems to make no difference.

```
--classpath="cldata/build/classes/java/main/uk/co/myproject/cldata/tables;backend/build/classes/java/main/uk/co/myproject/backend;backend/build/classes/java/main/uk/co/myproject/backend/datahelpers;backend/build/classes/java/main/uk/co/myproject/backend/entities" \
```

If anyone has any idea as to what the problem may be, I would be most grateful.
This unhelpful error message is very frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to get this command to work. However, I am using Android Studio & the **endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin**, which has solved the issue for my particular needs.

As mentioned on its [Github page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin), it provides a `endpointsOpenApiDocs` command to generate the OpenAPI doc.

I was able to use this to generate the openapi.json file by using Android Studio's Terminal to run:

```
../gradlew endpointsOpenApiDocs
```

from my Endpoints module's directory (I'm using the gradle wrapper, which lives up a level at the root of the project).

I hope this helps others who may end up in the same situation.